# Will the probability for tunnelling go completely to zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, probability, models, quantum-tunneling

According to quantum mechanics, the probability for quantum tunnelling (of an object) *never* become completely zero, no matter how "big" is the height and the thickness of the barrier.

However, it seems that the probability is being calculated using an *idealized model*: the mathematics is done in a pretend world where there are, for example, no other potentials about and there are no other interactions besides transmission and reflection from a lowish barrier.

So, here is the question. If one somehow is able to take into account the other potentials and the other interactions (besides transmission and reflection from a lowish barrier), will the probability for tunnelling go completely down to zero depending on how "big" is the height and the thickness of the barrier?

Comment: well, supposedly for an infinitely wide barrier the probability is 0. However, even for finite sized barriers it does not matter, if the probability is (eg) 1e-1000 or 1e-500, how could this ever be tested? In practical terms this is equivalent to 0, and of no consequence also in a theoretical framework. Its like saying human height follows a normal distribution and then interpreting it as "its possible a human will be born who will be 30m in height. Even more spectacular is that its almost as likely as a 100m one".

Comment: It's fairly easy to get extremely large numbers of atoms together in one place and wait for them to decay. Xenon and Tellurium for example have isotopes with half-lives in trillions of universe-lifetimes. If that's compared to the probability of a decay in an hour, we can experimentally distinguish between 0 and about $10^{-28}$. Nowhere close to the numbers Jose Andrade mentioned, but still awfully close to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Let's focus on slowly varying potentials in one dimension for concreteness. In the WKB approximation, the tunneling probability for a particle of mass $m$, energy $E$, and a generic potential $V(x)$ has the form $e^{-2\Gamma}$, where $\Gamma$ is an integral over the potential in the classically forbidden region $\Omega$ (bounded by $x_0$ and $x_1$)
\begin{equation}
\Gamma = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} dx \sqrt{\frac{2 m \left(V(x) - E\right)}{\hbar^2}} 
\end{equation}
$\Gamma$, and hence the tunneling probability, will always be finite so long as the potential and the volume of the classically forbidden region are both bounded. In particular, you would not expect a complicated superposition of potentials to make $\Gamma$ diverge.

Comment: A "complicated " superposition is pretty vague  word choice.

Comment: The main point is that the WKB approximation is a mathematical model of a world where there are no other potentials about and no other interactions besides transmission and reflection from a lowish barrier. Definitely, that's not the "real-life" world.

Comment: @IvNik If you want to be more formal, you can pretty easily derive a bound on $\Gamma$ based on the maximum value of $V$ and $x_1-x_0$ that will be finite so long as both $V_{\rm max}$ and $x_1-x_0$ are finite. Calculating the tunneling rate in more complicated systems still boils down to something like the integral in the WKB approximation. So long as the integral of the interaction energy never diverge you get a finite tunneling rate.

Comment: Again. The proposed model DOES NOT take into account all of the other potentials and all possible interactions besides transmission and reflection from a lowish barrier. That is not how the real world (Nature) works. And that's why I claim that such a model is problematic (although it could be useful anyway).

Comment: @IvNik Just a clarification about the WKB approximation. The barrier does not need to be "low-ish". The potential can have any height and width (accounting for an arbitrary interaction or set of interactions), so long as it is slowly varying compared to the wavelength of the particle.

Comment: Yup, that's right. Anyway. Do you think such a model describes the real world? Does it take care for all of the real potentials and all possible interactions (besides transmission and reflection)? That is not how the real-world Nature work, as it was already pointed out. Now that is somehow problematic. Although it is useful (in a certain sense) as a model.

Comment: @IvNik I do think it describes the real world. It is a valid mathematical approximation of an equation believed to be fundamental. I would say it is more than a model, on some level -- a specific model would be specifying a form for $V(x)$. I would say the expression I quoted is a generic prediction of quantum mechanics, in the WKB regime. Admittedly there is an approximation being made, but I would say a mild one. To actually get *zero* as a tunneling rate would be a very special answer. Generally you should not expect a physical quantity to turn out to be zero without a reason. (...)

Comment: (...) To me, what the WKB approximation to the tunneling rate shows explicitly is that you *can't* get zero as an answer, in the WKB regime. *Maybe* having a wildly varying potential will somehow change that behavior, but that seems unlikely. Furthermore, given any fixed potential, you can always find a regime where the WKB regime applies, but considering particles with high enough energy that their wavelength is shorter than the variations in the potential. (Unless you have some very pathological potential)

Comment: What do you mean by "mild" approximation? Once again, I do not argue that the model does not give precise and useful predictions. I claim that the model does not represent the real world because it does not take into account all of the other potentials and possible interactions. Such "details" does matter, when one is considering the real Nature... not merely searching for useful instrumentalistic model that "works extremely well". Don't you agree?